# errors in crontab file - don't see them

Tags: php, cron

I have the following file named crons.txt

In this file I have:

`*/2 * * * * wget -q -O - http://www.mydomain.com/testcron.php`

^ Should run every 2 minutes...

Now I go into SSH and enter the following command:

crontab /home/crons/game.txt

Which returns

"/home/crons/game.txt":0: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.

I'm not sure what im doing wrong, the command looks ok to me... Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that your cron command is on one line without line break.

Comment: Then I get: crontab /home/crons/game.txt
new crontab file is missing newline before EOF, can't install.

Comment: check here for more solutions http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/why-did-my-crontab-not-trigger

Comment: No ok, but after the cronjob on a single line, leave at least one empty line.

Comment: Probably better to use `/usr/bin/wget` (type `which wget` in your terminal to figure out the path).

Comment: I have a similar crontab on my system, but using curl instead of wget :-  `% crontab -l
*/3 * * * * curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080/safety/api?format"` and it works fine.